# Getting the coordinates of a moving SVG Circle which is moving over a path set in animateMotion

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I need to check the response of a user by tracking the mouse movement over a moving object (in this case a circle). If the mouse is not over the circle I need to calculate the offset by comparing the mouse coordinates and the circle coordinates.

But whenever I check the circle values, they are not changing and will stay on their initial value.

Here's a simple example:

```js
function clickCircle() {
  var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
  console.log('baseVal x: ' + circle.cx.baseVal.value);
  console.log('animVal x: ' + circle.cx.animVal.value);

}
```

```html
    <p>Click on the moving circle</p>
    <svg width="1200" height="1200"> 
        <circle id="circle" cx="60" cy="60" r="20" fill="green" onclick="clickCircle();"> 
            <animateMotion id="ani" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          path="M20, 60 C20, 
                -50 180, 150 180, 
                 60 C180-60 20, 
                 150 20, 60 z" /> 
        </circle> 
    </svg>
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to get the coordinates from a moving circle that is being animated with animateMotion?

Comment: Because you're not animating the circle's cx or cy. The animation you're applying acts as an additional transform on the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could drag in an animation Icon, and track its properties

[image]

Or with JavaScript you calculate its center x,y position with:

```
  let {width,height} = circle.getBBox();
  let {x,y} = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = x + width/2;
  y = y + height/2;
```

**Also read: https://schneide.blog/2018/03/05/some-tricks-for-working-with-svg-in-javascript/**

**note!** this code below will forever **add** circle Nodes!

```html
<style> svg { width: 300px } </style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 200">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="lightgreen"></rect>
    <text x=10 y="20">Click the circle!</text>
    <circle id="circle" cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="green" 
            onclick="clickCircle(event)">
    <animateMotion id="ani" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" path="m20 40c0-110 160 90 160 0c0-120-160 90-160 0z" />
    </circle>
    <text id="position" x="200" y="20">21</text>
</svg>
<script>
  function clickCircle(evt) {
    point("gold");
  }
  function point(color) {
    let circle = document.getElementById("circle");
    let {width,height} = circle.getBBox();
    let {x,y} = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
    let c = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
    x = x + width/2;
    y = y + height/2;
    c.setAttribute("cx", x);
    c.setAttribute("cy", y);
    c.setAttribute("r", color == "black" ? 3 : 6);
    c.setAttribute("fill", color);
    circle.parentNode.append(c);
    position.innerHTML = `${~~x} , ${~~y}`;
  }
  setInterval(() => point("black"), 250);
</script>
```

---

Or try the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dannye/ph705b49/

Dan was Authorware toch heel wat makkelijker...
Alles goed?

Comment: He Danny da's lang geleden!

En weet je wat nu de echte grap is: ik heb dit nodig omdat ik een heel oud Authorware programma moet omzetten! Dus dat plaatje van je was 'spot on' :-)

Hier is alles prima. Nog steeds lekker aan het programmeren. Nu ik Authorware weer open heb gehad is me opgevallen hoeveel ik er nog van weet, zelfs na al die jaren weet ik nog steeds heel veel shortcuts.